# Add one day to DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to add one  day to the current datetime for comparison later. I want to be able to turn of a feature in my app for one day if a user click on a button. So when the set datetime+24 hours is lower than the current datetime it will reactivate.

I know how to get the current datetime like this:

```
static DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

But I want to do this:

```
static DateTime deactivateDate = DateTime.UtcNow+24;
```

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: static DateTime deactivateDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `DateTime`? The `AddDays` method is what you're after...

Answer (score 5):

You can call:

```
static DateTime deactivateDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
```

or

```
static DateTime deactivateDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TimeSpan.FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) (or [TimeSpan.FromDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays.aspx)) method:

```
static DateTime deactivateDate = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly farfetched..

```
now.AddDays(1);
now.AddHours(24);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: `AddDays` and `AddHours` seem kind of cryptic. I wouldn't of thought it was that complex.